# How can I call proxy contract using .attach with ethersjs?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm trying to call my proxy contract (here is a github withe the code https://github.com/TheWeb3starter/minimal-proxy/blob/master/scripts/run.js#L21) but I got an error when I call it.

I guess it seems to be an issue with the `.attach()` part, but I wasn't able to solve it.

Thanks in advance!

```
  const Storage = await await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Storage");
  const storage = await Storage.deploy();
  // Attaching the new copy address to the storage
  const storage1 = await storage.attach(storageAddress1);

  // Setting some data
  await storage1.setData("abc");

  // Here it fails when I try to get the data
  const result = await storage1.getData();
  console.log(result);
```

[Image of an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yoJf.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deploy if you're not interacting or deploying the 'Storage' contract. Also your double await is redundant on the first line.

Try this:

```js
const Storage = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Storage");

// Attach here without first deploying
const storage1 = await Storage.attach(storageAddress1);

// Set some data
await storage1.setData("abc");

// Retrieve data
const result = await storage1.getData();
console.log(result);
```